# How do I make an arbitrary number of if conditions in lua that I could generate from another function?

Tags: string, if-statement, lua, conditional-statements

```
if (item.type >= startbag and item.type <= endbag) and not item.isuntradeable and item.equipslot ~= 0 and item.ishq then
    gFatCat.count.goodies = gFatCat.count.goodies + 1
    gFatCat.item.goodies[gFatCat.count.goodies] = item 
    ml_debug(string.format("[FatCat] - #% 3d - Count: %3d - Name: %s Bag: %d Slot: %d", gFatCat.count.goodies, item.count, item.name, item.type, item.slot))
end
```

I want to be able to reuse this piece of code. Is it possible to generate a string from a function somewhere and use that string for arbitrary number of if conditions? Let's say I wanna add `item.uicategory == 50` and/or `item.uicategory == 1` in there. Is it possible in lua? How would I approach this?

Comment: please improve your code. it is not 100% what you want to achieve.

Comment: Oh sorry for that, it is just a snippet from a function that I made. Somebody pointed out in the discord that I could do so by using a table for the if check but I don't know yet exactly how to do that. My guess is to make a table from the current item being iterated and compare it with a dynamically generated table that holds the actual checklist of conditions like (not item.isuntradeable and item.ishq and (item.uicategory == 1 or item.uicategory == 50 ...etc.)).